# What methods should i use to recognize distorted and kinked captchas?

Tags: python, ocr, captcha

I have an image of captcha and the problm is i dont know how to tackle visual recognition(CNN-wise (neural network) or through OCR library)

I tried to use simple cases from other stackoverflow questions but it seems that they are to simple as in my case they are overlaping and heavily distorted.

Example 1:

[image: captcha exampl 1]

Example 2:

[image: example 2]

```
for dilate in [1, 3, 4, 5]:
    for erode in [1, 3, 4, 5]:
        for thresh in [125, 150, 175, 200]:
            img = cv.imread('cap.png', 0)
            img = cv.resize(img, (300, 120))
            ret, img = cv.threshold(img, thresh, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
            img = cv.dilate(img, np.ones((dilate,dilate), np.uint8))
            img = cv.erode(img, np.ones((erode,erode), np.uint8))
            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 7 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
            print(text)
```

I would like to understand what methods should i use or where do i start. Is it better to train my own CNN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of spent time, i found an answer. I hope that if someone is interested in this topic, they would find my answer to their vague question complete :)
The fastest route to captcha solving lies not in segmentation(i havent found any answer on how to precisely get rid of all complex ligatures in captchas). Thus there is only one way to generate your train set of captchas and create CNN model.
Generating dataset is not easy if you dont know php as most of the captcha scripts are written in PHP. For me i found very useful generation script “kcaptcha” (it has distortions and wierd fonts).
CNN model is made not trivially as at the end of the model we would want it to have N outputs collapsed into one (where N number of letters).